# Empty entity field is not returning null in Spring Data for MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

I have the following structure for the entities:

```
@Document("attribute")
data class Attribute(
    @Id
    val id: String? = null,
    val name: String,
    @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
    val defaultValue: Value? = null,
)

@Document("value")
data class Value(
    @Id
    val id: String? = null,
    val name: String,
)
```

Whenever I query for some `Attribute` which doesn't have any `Value` assigned I get back some proxy object which has all of the fields `null` but itself it is not `null`.

It would look something like this in JSON format:

```
{
  "id": "abcdefg",
  "name": "SomeName",
  "defaultValue": {
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }
}
```

This causes some problems in Kotlin as I have specified these fields as not nullable.

I assume this happens because of this reference being lazy. Is there any way to disable this behavior other than removing `lazy = true`?